# JMeter 5.4 When open testplan Unexpected error

Tags: java, jmeter, windows-10

I create a very simple testplan:
[image]

1. I save the testplan as MySimpleTestplan.jmx
2. Close JMeter
3. Start JMeter again as: double click on jmeter.bat
4. JMeter starts
5. I browse to MySimpleTestplan.jmx and selects it
6. Unexpected error. Se image below:
7. [image]
8. I look in log

   WARN o.a.j.g.a.Load: Unexpected error. java.lang.NullPointerException
   java.lang.NullPointerException: null
   at java.util.ArrayDeque.addLast(ArrayDeque.java:304) ~[?:?]
   at java.util.ArrayDeque.add(ArrayDeque.java:495) ~[?:?]
   at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.LoadRecentProject.updateRecentFileMenuItems(LoadRecentProject.java:125) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4]
   at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar.setProjectFileLoaded(JMeterMenuBar.java:144) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4]
   at org.apache.jmeter.gui.MainFrame.setProjectFileLoaded(MainFrame.java:330) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4]
   at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.setTestPlanFile(GuiPackage.java:732) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4]
   at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:136) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4]
   at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:101) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4]
   at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.doActionAfterCheck(Load.java:88) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4]
   at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.AbstractActionWithNoRunningTest.doAction(AbstractActionWithNoRunningTest.java:44) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4]
   at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:87) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4]
   at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionRouter.java:69) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4]
   at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313) [?:?]
   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770) [?:?]
   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721) [?:?]
   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715) [?:?]
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:?]
   at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85) [?:?]
   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740) [?:?]
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203) [?:?]
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124) [?:?]
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113) [?:?]
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109) [?:?]
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101) [?:?]
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90) [?:?]
   2020-12-09 16:54:04,150 ERROR o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: Unexpected error - see log for details

My Java version is: javac 11.0.8
JMeter version: 5.4
I'm really stuck here.

Comment: Periodically this version could not save test plan as a new file... (( very sad. The exception is the same - NPE

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Errors](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jmeter-user/202012.mbox/browser) are known issues in 5.4 version and will be fixed soon on release 5.4.1, answered by @FelixSchumacher

> you hit https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64957 This regression will be fixed by a release (probably soon), but in the mean time you can try a current build from trunk or a nightly build (https://jmeter.apache.org/nightly.html)

If you don't want to downgrade, take new version from [JMeter downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi)

Comment: Thanks @user7294900 :-) I downgraded to older version of JMeter and it now works just fine. Thanks again.

Comment: @user3624378 If you don't want to downgrade, another option is to take latest JMeter build https://ci-builds.apache.org/job/JMeter/job/JMeter-trunk/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/src/dist/build/distributions/apache-jmeter-5.4.1-SNAPSHOT.zip

Comment: Does this bug only affect the Open Recent menu, does anybody know? If so I can live with that, but it's not clear whether that is the only effect.

Comment: @VinceBowdren it's related to running in JMeter GUI, non in CLI mode