# Jmeter 5.4 - java.lang.NullPointerException in thread Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main]

Tags: jmeter

Trying to use the latest Jmeter version 5.4, however when imported the recorded script using Blazemeter to Jmeter and tried to disable/perform any action on Jmeter UI, getting the below error.

```
Uncaught Exception java.lang.NullPointerException in thread Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main]. See log file for details.
```

I have Java 8, earlier Jmeter versions worked fine. Facing this issue with the latest version only.

**jmeter.log file:**

```
 2021-01-21 17:34:33,542 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main]
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.github.weisj.darklaf.ui.cell.hint.CellHintPopupListener.lambda$enter$0(CellHintPopupListener.java:234) ~[darklaf-core-2.4.10.jar:2.4.10]
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_231]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_231]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_231]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_231]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_231]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_231]
2021-01-21 17:34:50,507 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main]
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.github.weisj.darklaf.ui.cell.hint.CellHintPopupListener.lambda$enter$0(CellHintPopupListener.java:234) ~[darklaf-core-2.4.10.jar:2.4.10]
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_231]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_231]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_231]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_231]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_231]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_231]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JMeter 5.4 When open testplan Unexpected error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65220327/jmeter-5-4-when-open-testplan-unexpected-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're experiencing [JMeter Bug 64957](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64957) there are following options:

1. Downgrade to [JMeter 5.3](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-5.3/), it can be downloaded from [JMeter archives](https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/) folder
2. Upgrade to a [nightly build](https://jmeter.apache.org/nightly.html), it can be downloaded from [Jenkins](https://ci-builds.apache.org/job/JMeter/job/JMeter-trunk/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/src/dist/build/distributions/)

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri, will continue using Jmeter 5.3 version.